# Bootstrap align-middle text not applied in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertical align text (`<span class="align-middle">middle</span>`) in the middle of a div.

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-4 shadow product-added">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <div class="row">
            <img src="<?php echo $OTHERIMAGE1; ?>" class="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">
          <span class="align-middle">middle</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why isn't the text aligning as it should?

Comment: Try putting the class on the parent div

Comment: Thanks for checking, already tried, but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually working but it is doing it inside the span because align-middle only works with inline elements.

You should use it on the parent div but with the class d-flex align-items-center

```
<div class="col-7 d-flex align-items-center">
```

I saved it on a JSfiddle while adding height to the row to see if it would work correctly:

https://jsfiddle.net/vca42kxo/2/